# 1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1 line 27 but there is not error on line 27?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I see a lots a answer about this problem but my is a little different. I'm using flash 4.5 PHP and the adobe CS Extension builder SDK. I just started to get the this error :

```
'1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1. 27 Flex Problem'
```

However, I double click on the error and it don't bring me to any error? I went through all my *.as files and I can't find a mark error anywhere in any of my code? 
I'm not sure how to fix something I can't find? has anyone else run into this problem?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean you're using Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP?  Is this a compile time error?  Have you tried cleaning your project?  If it's still there, have you tried cleaning your workspace?  (Clean the workspace by launching Flash Builder with the '-clean' command line argument)

Comment: yes I'm using flash builder 4.5 and yes I have clean my  project but not my workspace  which I'm going to do right now.. this si run time error

Comment: Ok clean the workspace and still the same freaking error.

Comment: If it's a runtime error cleaning won't help. Usually this kind of error tells you exactly which method of which class throws the error. I don't know "adobe CS Extension builder SDK" though...

Comment: Yea, I understand that but it don't tell me anything other than there is a argument is missing a parameter, i try clicking on it but it don't bring me to the error which is strange txs anyway

Comment: My intuition is that there is something off w/ your code; I just don't know what.  Do you have a misplaced quoted or an extra bracket somewhere?  You may try creating a new project and moving code in class by class...

Comment: I think thats just what I have to do.. txs again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Flex produces errors when you set strange connections as an binding. What you can do is to set the commandline argument -keep-generated-actionscript to true.
The compiler generates now a genrated folder in yor source folder with all the genrated as classes from your mxml files. You could then try to compile them alone. Mybe you find the eror then. I did this a few times because of errors in the generated mxml/as code.