# Migrating from Flex 3.5 to Flex 4.6 : error 1137

Tags: apache-flex, migration, flex4, flex3

when migrating an existing app from flex 3.5 to 4.6 we have the following error :

```
Description          Resource          Path          Location          Type
1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 1.          "Project_name"                    line 0          Flex Problem
```

and we cannot understand where it comes from, since it is on line 0 of resource "Project_name" with no path specified. It's just too generic for us to track down.
What could this be due to?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question is almost an year old and the answer may no longer be important, but anyway, this question may have been answered by the solutions provided for the other similar questions:
1) [Error migrating Flex 3 to Flex 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025649/error-migrating-flex-3-to-flex-4)

or
2) [1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1 line 27 but there is not error on line 27?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721673/1136-incorrect-number-of-arguments-expected-1-line-27-but-there-is-not-error-o)